# Spllit an array in Javascript for Google Apps Script function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Current result has this:

```
[
['Cycling','Chess'],
['Cycling','Pilates'],
['Cycling','Elevate'],
['Cycling','Kundalini'],
['Cycling','Scrabble'],
['Cycling','Crossword'],
['Cycling','Darning'],
['Running','Ashtanga'],
['Running','Poker'],
['Running','Sudoku'],
['Running','Sewing'],
['Running','Jump'],
['Boxing','Mushin'],
['Boxing','Tai'],
['Boxing','Tae'],
['Boxing','1000'],
['Boxing','Transient'],
['Boxing','Walking'],
['Strength','Flow'],
['Strength','Tantric'],
['Strength','Quigong'],
['Strength','Active']
]
```

Split the array so  that only the following remains:

```
['Chess'],
['Pilates'],
['Elevate'],
['Kundalini'],
['Scrabble'],
['Crossword'],
['Darning'],
['Ashtanga'],
['Poker'],
['Sudoku'],
['Sewing'],
['Jump'],
['Mushin'],
['Tai'],
['Tae'],
['1000'],
['Transient'],
['Walking'],
['Flow'],
['Tantric'],
['Quigong'],
['Active']
```

Split only appears to work on 1 dimension arrays so I'm looking for an alternative. Numpty has an hsplit function but unable to find an equivalent for Javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `map` method, here's sample code:

```js
const arr = [
['Cycling','Chess'],
['Cycling','Pilates'],
['Cycling','Elevate'],
['Cycling','Kundalini'],
['Cycling','Scrabble'],
['Cycling','Crossword'],
['Cycling','Darning'],
['Running','Ashtanga'],
['Running','Poker'],
['Running','Sudoku'],
['Running','Sewing'],
['Running','Jump'],
['Boxing','Mushin'],
['Boxing','Tai'],
['Boxing','Tae'],
['Boxing','1000'],
['Boxing','Transient'],
['Boxing','Walking'],
['Strength','Flow'],
['Strength','Tantric'],
['Strength','Quigong'],
['Strength','Active']
];

const new_arr = arr.map( element => {
return [element[1]];
});

console.log(new_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `arr.map(subarr => [subarr[1]])`, though I don't see why you want one-element lists. `arr.map(subarr => subarr[1])`, producing a list of strings, is probably more useful.

```js
const arr = [
  ['Cycling','Chess'],
  ['Cycling','Pilates'],
  ['Cycling','Elevate'],
  ['Cycling','Kundalini'],
  ['Cycling','Scrabble'],
  ['Cycling','Crossword'],
  ['Cycling','Darning'],
  ['Running','Ashtanga'],
  ['Running','Poker'],
  ['Running','Sudoku'],
  ['Running','Sewing'],
  ['Running','Jump'],
  ['Boxing','Mushin'],
  ['Boxing','Tai'],
  ['Boxing','Tae'],
  ['Boxing','1000'],
  ['Boxing','Transient'],
  ['Boxing','Walking'],
  ['Strength','Flow'],
  ['Strength','Tantric'],
  ['Strength','Quigong'],
  ['Strength','Active']
];
console.log(arr.map(subarr => [subarr[1]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to create a dictionary, so you "deduplicate" data on the same iteration. This code only works for arrays with 2 items. You can easily iterate over that array so you can use it with arrays of any size

```js
var arr = [
['Cycling','Chess'],
['Cycling','Pilates'],
['Cycling','Elevate'],
['Cycling','Kundalini'],
['Cycling','Scrabble'],
['Cycling','Crossword'],
['Cycling','Darning'],
['Running','Ashtanga'],
['Running','Poker'],
['Running','Sudoku'],
['Running','Sewing'],
['Running','Jump'],
['Boxing','Mushin'],
['Boxing','Tai'],
['Boxing','Tae'],
['Boxing','1000'],
['Boxing','Transient'],
['Boxing','Walking'],
['Strength','Flow'],
['Strength','Tantric'],
['Strength','Quigong'],
['Strength','Active']
]

const data = Object.keys(arr.reduce((prev, act) => {
  prev[act[0]] = 1
  prev[act[1]] = 1
  return prev
}, {}))

console.log(data)
```